# Computing diameter of a 3D polyhedron

Tags: graph-algorithms, polytope

A polyhedron is given as a set of its vertex coordinates. Is it possible to find its diameter faster than $O(n^2)$?

Or, maybe, some another common polyhedron representation would help fasten this?

Comment: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=336215 $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/gaertner/miniball.html

Comment: sshilovsky: miniball is a different problem, and is easier to solve quickly.

Comment: And if you want a practical algorithm:
http://sarielhp.org/p/00/diam.html